# How to link QCA to my Qt project?

Tags: c++, qt, dynamic-linking

I have successfully cloned [git repository of QCA](https://github.com/KDE/qca) and built it using

```
cmake .
make
sudo make install
```

This created `bin` directory with some executables and I can confirm everything works as should by running

```
$ bin/qcatool-qt5 plugins
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins
  /home/metheuser/qtcreator/qca/bin
Available Providers:
  qca-gnupg
  qca-logger
  qca-ossl
    This product includes cryptographic software written by Eric Young
    (eay@cryptsoft.com)
  qca-softstore
```

However when I specify in my Qt project:

```
QT += crypto
```

I get this error

> Unknown module(s) in QT: crypto

I have no idea how to include the library now. I have tried adding this to my .pro file:

```
LIBS += -lqca
```

and

```
LIBS += -lqca2
```

Both resulting in error:

> cannot find -lqca

What should I do? I followed the official README/INSTALL instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add the lib path to your .pro file. So, Instead of

```
LIBS += -lqca
```

you need

```
LIBS += -L$${PATH_QCA_LIB} -lqca
```